# How to properly implement data binding for a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, sorteddictionary, inotifycollectionchanged

In a WPF application, I am using a `DataGrid` on my main window.  The data that it displays is from a `SortedDictionary<int, Individual>` , where `Individual` is a class containing a person’s name and other facts. Specifically, the data comes from the `SortedDictionary`’s `Values` property.

Apparently, `SortedDictionary` does not implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface so, after having displayed the original set of `Values`, if I `Add` or `Remove` an entry to the dictionary, the UI does not get notified and trouble ensues.

After researching this much on the web, I didn’t get a decent idea of how to go about fixing this so the UI gets properly notified.  None of the posts I saw involved a `SortedDictionary`.

The main features of the `SortedDictionary` that I use are `Add`, `Remove`, and `Item[TKey]`.

Can someone please advise me or point me to an example of how to really do this?

In the XAML for my main window I have:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPeople" Margin="23" SelectionChanged="dgSelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                  IsEnabled="False"  TextSearch.TextPath="paternalSurname" MouseDoubleClick="dgPeoplePersonDoubleClicked" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="1125" MinHeight="435" SizeChanged="dgSizeChanged" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="PeachPuff" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcPaternalSurname" Header="Paternal Surname" Width="150" Binding="{Binding paternalSurname}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcMaternalSurname" Header="Maternal Surname" Width="150" Binding="{Binding maternalSurname}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcNames" Header="Names" Width="360" Binding="{Binding names}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcState" Header="S" Width="17" Binding="{Binding state}" MinWidth="17" MaxWidth="17"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcBirthDate" Header="Birth Date" Width="120" Binding="{Binding birthDate}" MaxWidth="120" MinWidth="120" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgtcBirthPlace" Header="Birth Place" Width="320" Binding="{Binding birthPlace}" MaxWidth="320" MinWidth="320" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

In the constructor for the window that has the `DataGrid` I have:

```
dgPeople.ItemsSource = db.people.Values;
dgPeople.IsTextSearchEnabled = true;
dgPeople.IsTextSearchCaseSensitive = false;

CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgPeople.ItemsSource);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("normalizedPaternal", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("normalizedNames", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Comment: Since there are several slightly different XAML formats, would please clarify whether this is WPF, UWP, Xamarin, Avalonia, etc? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to display sorted data, you could consider using an `ObservableCollection` as data store, set it as the `DataSource` of a `BindingSource` object, and then set the [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.sort) property of this object.

Comment: This is a WPF application.

Comment: Questions asking for a referral to code examples and other resources are off-topic. Questions asking for from-scratch implementations of specific functionality are too broad.  You have a variety of options, including implementing your own dictionary that does support `INotifyCollectionChanged`, maintain a parallel data structure in an `ObservableCollection<T>` that mirrors your values, or forcing the whole binding to refresh any time the dictionary changes. **Try something.** Then if you still have problems, post a question with a [mcve] and details about what _specifically_ you need help with